# Upper method doesn't make sense

Tags: python

**Code**:

```
def solve_the_input(port):
    port = hex(int(port))
    split_result = port.split("0x")
    split_port = split_result[1]
    print 'input port is ',split_port
    split_port.upper()
    print 'input port is ',split_port
    return split_port

if __name__ == "__main__":
    if len(sys.argv) == 1:
        print "please input a port"
    else:
        port = solve_the_input(sys.argv[1])
```

**Input**

```
python test.py 42328
```

**Actual Output**:

```
input port is  a558
input port is  a558
```

**Expected Output**:

```
input port is  a558
input port is  A558
```

I don't know why the upper() method is not working as expected.

Comment: Basic rule of python:  string methods do not alter the string - they can't because strings are immutable (read-only) - so they always return a new string object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couple of points

- `split_port.upper()` return is not assigned back to `split_port`
- No need to split on `'0x'`. You can use `replace` function instead. Will be less complicated.

**Code with replace function:**

```
import sys
def solve_the_input(port):
    port = hex(int(port))
    result = port.replace("0x",'')
    print 'input port is ',result
    result = result.upper()
    print 'input port is ',result
    return result

if __name__ == "__main__":
   if len(sys.argv) == 1:
       print "please input a port"
   else :
       port = solve_the_input(sys.argv[1])
```

**Output:**

```
C:\Users\dinesh_pundkar\Desktop>python c.py 1235
input port is  4d3
input port is  4D3

C:\Users\dinesh_pundkar\Desktop>
```

Answer (score 2):

The upper method returns *new* string in uppercase. So use

```
split_port = split_result[1].upper()
```

Answer (score 0):

Upper method returning new string but you need to store that string.

```
split_port = split_result[1].upper()
```